# export json data as csv in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hey guys I'm trying to add a download button in order to export some Json data as csv but this is not working for me. The data i want to export is inside `shareFilterHead` and `shareFilterRows` and the data is in Json. I'm using the CsvDownloader from 'react-csv-downloader'.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import DynamicTable from '@atlaskit/dynamic-table';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import CsvDownloader from 'react-csv-downloader';

export default class ShareFilter extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      shareFilterRows: []
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(AJS.contextPath() + "/rest/securityrestresource/1.0/results?check=ShareFilter")
    .then((res)=>{
        if(res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        }
    }).then((res)=>{
  this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    shareFilterRows: res.map((row, index) => ({
      key: `row-${index}-${row.filterID}`,
      cells: [{
        key: `${row.filterID}`,
        content: row.filterID,
        },
        {
        key: `${row.author}`,
        content: row.author,
        },
        {
        key: `${row.filtername}`,
        content: row.filtername,
        },
        {
        key: `${row.jql}`,
        content: row.jql,
        },]}))
  })
  })
  }

render() {
const { error, isLoaded, shareFilterRows } = this.state;
if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading Shared Filters...</div>;
} else {
  return (<Wrapper>
    <div>
    <DynamicTable
      head={shareFilterHead}
      rows={shareFilterRows}
      rowsPerPage={10}
      defaultPage={1}
      loadingSpinnerSize="large"
      isLoading={false}
      isFixedSize
      defaultSortKey="filterID"
      defaultSortOrder="ASC"
      onSort={() => console.log('onSort')}
      onSetPage={() => console.log('onSetPage')}
      
      />
  </div>
  </Wrapper>
  );
  }
}
}



AJS.toInit(function () {
AJS.$(document).on("click", "#downloadShareFilterCheck", function(){

    <CsvDownloader
    filename="myfile"
    extension=".csv"
    separator=";"
    wrapColumnChar="'"
    columns={shareFilterHead}
    datas={shareFilterRows}
    text="DOWNLOAD" />


});
}
```

Comment: Where is `AJS` declared?

Comment: Are you sure clicking  on `#downloadShareFilterCheck` worked?

Comment: @VitaliyRayets the button works fine I'm sure

Comment: Can you add more information how it's not working, you have errors or something else

Comment: When i click on the button that triggers the download, nothing happens